# MongDB Aggregate two values with same name

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregate

i have the following aggregate function in my code to count how many times a value is found in the db:

```
  let data: any = await this.dataModel.aggregate(
      [
        {
          $match: {
            field: new ObjectID(fieldID),
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$value",
            total_for_value: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
      ]
    );
```

This works correctly, however my data setup is a bit different. I have two types of value fields. Some like this:

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("123"),
    "value" : "MALE"
    }
```

and some like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("456"),
    "value" : {
        "value" : "MALE",
    }
}
```

Is there a way to group the ones where the _id and the _id.value are the same? At the moment it counts them separately.

Comment: sample documents?

Comment: Create three group stages. One for your `_id`, one for `_id.value` and then one for grouping both of those.

Comment: @Gibbs just added some sample docs now

Comment: Please have a look at my edited solution, let me know @TestUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "key2": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $and: [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  {
                    "$type": "$key"
                  },
                  "object"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "then": "$key.value",
          "else": "$key"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$key2",
      "data": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This would do the job if `_id.value` is an object.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BPOzMpzlzoQ)

Comment: Thanks, but that only adds the "key2" field to the ones with value.value. So the ones with just value aren't being counted

Comment: Both are counted, that is a if-else.

Comment: but the key2 field is not being added to all of them. The ones without a value.value are being grouped as 'undefined'

Comment: Instead of key, could you try - value please. So value.value or just value. I think that is why it isn't working

Comment: is there a way to make sure any value objects are not empty? And filter out any empty ones that do not contain a value.value? @Gibbs

Comment: You can add a match stage with $size check